# billing.save(); shipping.save(); functions override in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, php, php-7

I need to override `billing.save();` & `shipping.save();`  functions but I don't know in which files they have their declarations in Magento.

I am new in Magento directory.

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

These prototype js objects use in checkout. They defines in **skin/frontend/base/default/js/opcheckout.js** file.
and adds to resulting html in onepage.html file using script html tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('js/opcheckout.js') ?>"></script>
```

To override save functions' logic you can add your own billing.phtml and shipping.phtml files in own theme and there add new logic for save method. For example to override billing.save() logic you need to add new javascript tag with following code : `if ('Billing' in window){
    Object.extend(Billing, {
        save: function(){
            //put your changes here
        }
    })
}`

or, also you can just override any function after object will be created, example put this code after `var billing = new Billing('co-billing-form', '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/getAddress') ?>address/', '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/saveBilling') ?>');`:

```
billing.save = function() {
    //your code here
}
```

Comment: As a complement, here is what I usually do to override a prototype method :
I use the "wrap" feature.
1) First you need to call another js file after the native opcheckout.js 
2) In this new file opcheckout-override.js, you can override what you want using "wrap".
For example, you can write something as :
`Billing.prototype.save = Billing.prototype.save.wrap(function (parentMethod) {

// Do here what you want and call the native method if you want :
parentMethod();

// Do here what you want
});
`